# Find the solution prime number p is divisir of cubic equation

Tags: number-theory

Find all prime numbers p for which there exists a unique a ∈ {1, 2, . . . , p} such
that
$a^3 − 3a + 1$ is divisible by p.

When I see the solution of this problem , the first think I surprised was we need to find the root of this equation, and I think this isn't related to some normal solution .

My question is how root of this cubic equation is related to the solution divisible by p ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urw3U.jpg)

Comment: Try it first with, say $p=2$ and $p=3$.

Comment: $p\mid f(a)\iff x=a\,$ is a root of $f(x)$ in $\Bbb Z_p,\,$ that's the "root" view of the problem. Is that clear?

Comment: What is "the solution of this problem" that you see?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I have added it, but I don't understand much the solution